# Using dataproxy method gives an error

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I try to use the dataProxy method in order to transmit parameters and one image to my server (jqgrid version 4.5.2).
Firebug gives me an error: d.p.dataProxy is undefined (jquery.jqGridmin.js line 298).
Here is the code:

```
.navGrid('#pager1',
        {edit:false,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:true},
        { 
          //edit 
        },
        {                     
            jqModal:true,
            resize:false,
            url:'url_1.php',                           
            reloadAftersubmit:true,
            closeAfterAdd:true,
            recreateForm:true,


            onInitializeForm: function (formid)
            {   
                $(formid).attr('method','POST');
                $(formid).attr('enctype','multipart/form-data');
                $(formid).attr('action','');    
            },
            useDataProxy:true,
            dataProxy: function (opts,act)
            {
                opts.url = 'url_2.php';
                opts.iframe = true;

                var $form = $('#FrmGrid_' + $(this).getGridParam('id'));

                //use normal ajax-call when no files to upload
                if($form.find(':file[value!=""]').size() == 0)
                {
                    $.ajax(opts);
                    return;
                }

                //Prevent non-file inputs double serialization
                var ele = $form.find(':input').not(':file');

                ele.each(function()
                {
                    $(this).data('name', $(this).attr('name'));
                    $(this).removeAttr('name');
                });

                //Send only previously generated data + files
                $form.ajaxSubmit(opts);

                //Set names back after form being submitted
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    ele.each(function()
                    {
                        $(this).attr('name', $(this).data('name'));
                    });
                }, 200);
            },
            afterSubmit: function (reponse,postdata)
            {    
                alert('aftersubmit');
                return [true,''];   
            }
        }, // (Add Options)
```

What is missing ?
A breakpoint on the dataproxy function is never fired.
As this method is not documented then it's not easy to use it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function `dataProxy` must be defined as jqGrid callback (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events)) and not as `prmEdit` or `prmAdd` parameter of of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition). You should move the code of `dataProxy` to the list of jqGrid options. The option `useDataProxy` are used in your code on the correct place. For details of usage `dataProxy` I would forward you to [the part](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L807-L834) of jqGrid code.

Comment: Is it possible to have two dataproxy callbacks: one for addition, one for edition ?

Comment: I could check the value of opts.data.oper